# Which familiars can't Akatsuki Kojou control by season 3 of the anime?

Tags: strike-the-blood

In season 3 episode 7, Akatsuki Kojou is told he can't win the duel with another vampire because in spite of he's the 4th primogenitor, and that's he supposed to be very powerful due to the familiars he has, he's going to lose the duel because he can't control them. But he showed to be able to control a lot of familiars at this point.

Which familiars can't Akatsuki Kojou control by season 3 of the anime?

Comment: 12th familiar is avrora who is in hospital.. At the end of season 3 he has 11 familiars..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now he cannot control 2 Familiars, it's the 6th and 8th one.

### Those are the ones he got so far:

Season 1 EP 4

- Control over 5th Familiar

Season 1 EP 8

- Control over 9th Familiar

Season 1 EP 12

- Control over 3rd Familiar

Season 1 EP 16

- Control over 12th Familiar

Season 1 EP 19

- Control over 4th Familiar

Season 1 EP 22

- Control over 11th Familiar

Season 2 EP 3

- Control over 7th Familiar

Season 2 EP 5

- Control over 1st Familiar

Season 2 EP 8

- Control over 2nd Familiar

Season 3 EP 3

- Control over 10th Familiar